# How do I add projects to my list of favorites on Google Code?

Tags: favorites

In Google Code there is a list of favorites. How do I add projects to my list of favorites?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The above answer is not correct.  You can "star" a project (upper left corner of project home page, in the sidebar), which adds it to your list of favorites without being a participant in the project.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I totally overlooked it although I clicked the +1 Button ;)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know this is automatically done for every project you participate in. You can not manually add a project to your favorites.